# clear editText randomNumber

Tags: java, android

I want to reset the number edit text field to be empty after every try.

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    int guessValue = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
    String message;

    if (guessValue > randomNumber) {
        message = "Lower !";
    } else if (guessValue < randomNumber) {
        message = "Higher";
    } else {
        message = "You got it! Try again";
        generateRandomNumber();
    }
```

Comment: please note i am a student and a beginner........

Comment: You have posted the code, so do you want to empty your editText after this code?

Comment: you should be able to do that with EditText.setText() method

Comment: yes it should clear the number you enter when it is not the correct one

Answer (score 0):

You can clear your text by using `.getText().clear()` methods, 
I've posted below the sample which can help you to understand how to clear your textbox.

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().clear();
```

**Applicable in your code**

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); 
    int guessValue = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()); 
    editText.getText().clear(); 
    String message; 

    if (guessValue > randomNumber) { 
        message = "Lower !"; 
    } 
    else if (guessValue < randomNumber) { 
        message = "Higher"; 
    } 
    else { 
        message = "You got it ! Try again"; generateRandomNumber(); 
    }
```

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what i wanted it to do.......... EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        int guessValue = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

        String message;

        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().clear();

        if (guessValue > randomNumber) {

            message = "Lower !";

        } else if (guessValue < randomNumber) {

            message = "Higher";

        } else {

            message = "You got it ! Try again";

            generateRandomNumber();

        }

Comment: When you have already assigned editText on `EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);` then you doesn't need to write  your code like `((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().clear();`

I've updated my answer you can verify it once.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
int guessValue = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
editText.getText.clear();  //or editText.setText("");
String message;

if (guessValue > randomNumber) {
    message = "Lower !";
} else if (guessValue < randomNumber) {
    message = "Higher";
} else {
    message = "You got it! Try again";
    generateRandomNumber();
}
```